# Import Django does not work on virtualenv(ubuntu)

Tags: python, django

I am trying something like this

```
source my_env/bin/activate
```

Then I check if Django is installed

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.9.13
```

But import fails

```
import django
```

Only cross appears. How to fix Django import?

Comment: Where does the cross appear? In your IDE? Are you sure you set the interpreter in your IDE to refer to the python bin installed in the VirtualEnv?

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns Well I am running everything from terminal.I can create django-admin startproject mysite latter,but I am confuesd why import fails.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean with "only cross appears". Could you clarify where this cross appears?

Comment: I am not lying to you,cross shows on the cursor.I can not take a screenshot because of this.

Comment: Are you typing `import django` directly into your shell? You need to run `python` first, then run `import django` in the Python shell.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes,that is the right solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running `import django` in your bash shell. This is running `import` from Imagemagick.

```
$ import django
```

Instead, you should start the Python shell, then run `import django` in the Python shell.

```
$ python  # or python manage.py shell
>>> import django
```